# Struts2 Localization redirect to current page

Tags: localization, struts

I had implemented Struts2 localization from [Localization 1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_localization.htm) and [Localization 2](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-i18n-or-localization-example/.) but both of these tutorial only show how to redirect to the index.jsp which different from my requirement.

My requirement is when user clicks the localization link at addCustomer.jsp, user will redirect to addCustomer.jsp with selected locale rather than to default pages (index.jsp).

How to achieve this?

EDIT

My link is like this:

```
<s:url id="locale_en" action="locale" namespace="/">
    <s:param name="request_locale">en</s:param>
</s:url>
<s:url id="locale_ms" action="locale" namespace="/">
    <s:param name="request_locale">ms</s:param>
</s:url>

<s:a href="%{locale_en}">English</s:a>
<s:a href="%{locale_ms}">Malay</s:a>
```

I have an idea like pass the current page as parameter to LocaleAction and the LocaleAction will redirect to the respective page. How to get param from Action?

Thanks.

Comment: I had solved it using the above idea. Any better idea?

Comment: I had solved it using the above idea with static mapping on each jsp and lookup using LocaleAction then based on the param return the appropriate string result. Any better idea?

Comment: always mark struts2 questions with struts2 tag and not with struts as both are different

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<s:url id="localeEN">
  <s:param name="request_locale" >en_US</s:param>
</s:url>
```

Struts2 link

```
<s:a href="%{localeEN}" >your text</s:a>
```